# How to create an insufficient balance message when the balance is 0?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div id="balance">0.00</div>
<div id="sum">0.01</div>
<div id="result">000</div>
<div id="message">000</div>
<button>ROLL</button>
```

```js
var x = 0;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function () {
    
    var num = setInterval(function () {
    $("#result").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
    }, 10);

    setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(num);
     var sum = parseFloat($("#sum").html());
     var fnal = $("#result").html();
     if (fnal > 50) {
        x += sum;
        $("#balance").text(x.toFixed(2));
        $("#message").text("Balance insufficient!");
      } 
      else {
        x -= sum;
        $("#balance").text(x.toFixed(2));
        $("#message").text("Balance insufficient!");
      }

    },500);
  });
});
```

I don't know how to do this within (if) and (else) instruction.
So, please how can I do this? and I'll appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please try to this code i hope helpfull thanks.

var x = 0;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function () {
    
    var num = setInterval(function () {
    $("#result").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
    }, 10);

    setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(num);
     var sum = parseFloat($("#sum").html());
     var fnal = $("#result").html();
     if (true) {
        x += sum;
        $("#balance").text(x.toFixed(2));
         $("#message").text(x === 0 ? "Balance insufficient!" : '');
      } 
      else {
        x -= sum;
        $("#balance").text(x.toFixed(2));
        $("#message").text(x === 0 ? "Balance insufficient!" : '');
      }

    },500);
  });
});
```

Comment: `if (true) {` is incorrect there, original shows ` if (fnal > 50) {` which you can keep. Other than that, its duplicate code and can be placed outside the `if/else` as Ive shown in my answer

Comment: Yes (true) was incorrect. no problem, bro. I used your code it works fine. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the balance and message out of the `if/else` to show a message when `x === 0`. Is this what youre looking for?

```js
var x = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var num = setInterval(function() {
      $("#result").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    }, 10);

    setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(num);
      var sum = parseFloat($("#sum").html());
      var fnal = parseFloat($("#result").html());
      if (fnal > 50) {
        x += sum;
      } else {
        x -= sum;
      }
      
      // Moved out of if/else, because it was the same
      $("#balance").text(x.toFixed(2));
      // If x === 0, show message, otherwise clear the text
      $("#message").text(x === 0 ? "Balance insufficient!" : '');

    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Note: if you havent seen the `<condition? ? <true> : <false>` yet, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem in the question, so that it is useful for other users also.

Comment: Edited to have a bit more explanation on what I changed

Comment: Thanks so much. Sir. I really appreciated it.